# C# can't add MySQL dataSource

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. I installed the latest connector from MySQL official download page. After installing the connector, I installed the MySQL Visual Studio integration, using their installer.
After doing this, I created a new project, then I added a dataSet to the project. I added a reference to MySQL.Data.dll to it.
Then I went to Server Explorer, accessed my connection to the MySQL server that I want to connect to, and I dragged a table from there into the dataset page. That resulted in an error that says:

> Mouse drag operation failed.
>
> Cannot obtain provider factory for data
> provider named 'MySql.Data.MySQLClient'

What is going on? Why cant I access mysql from Visual Studio? What provider factory?
I am using the ULTIMATE version of VS. What super-ultimate version should I use in order to be able to use MySQL?

Same thing happens if I go to the Data Sources tab and try to add my mysql database there

Comment: I think you must use the MySQL Workbench. I don't think you can do it from VS. But looking at the error do you have a reference to MySql.Data.MySQLClient?

Comment: What do you mean I should use MySQL Workbench? For a C# project ?!?! And no I do not have a reference to MySql.Data.MySQLClient because I cannot find it as a dll file... there are only these assemblies available: MySQL.Data, MySQL.Data.CF, MYSQL.Data.Entity, MySql.Fabric.Plugin and MySql.Web

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a datasource by using the datasource wizard in order to drag and drop e.g. a table on a form.

In order to get the wizard work you should use

Connector/Net 6.9.8 and MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6.

Other (newer) combinations will provide you with numerous errors